# How to validate the file name of the Media File Uploads?

Tags: uploads, media

I want to validate the file name of the files to be uploaded from the Media Library.

CASE study: I want to restrict the file name containing '%', '. .', '/' etc..from uploading to the media library.

I can restrict the file types but not able to restrict as per the file names.

Suggest me any wordpress filter or any procedure to accomplish the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The filter is `sanitize_file_name`. You get the `$filename` as parameter.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'wpse_77892_filter_filename' );

function wpse_77892_filter_filename( $filename )
{
    return str_replace( '%', '-', $filename );
}
```

See my plugin [Germanix URL](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) for an extended example.

Comment: Hello toscho,

I already thought of using sanitize_file_name but when we sanitize the file it doesn't restrict the file. Instead the file name was rewritten in a sanitized format. e.g. file name 'best picture/new.jpg' may become 'best-picture-new.jpg' after sanitization. But what I want is not to allow the file to be uploaded. My solution is more near to the function like validiate_file in wordpress.

Comment: But you get the name _after_ the upload. Whatever you do, you cannot prevent to upload based on the filename (file type is a different story). So it would be very frustrating for the user to waste time with an upload and then getting no usable result. Just change the name on the server side.

Comment: Ok toscho, thanks for your prompt reply. I have been going through your plugin code. Now can you just give me an idea how your plugin will sanitize this particular file name i.e. 'malic.html%00.jpg'

Comment: It will remove the `%` and leave the rest intact.

Comment: what about the dot '.' after 'malic'

Comment: Valid character, doesn’t do any harm.

Comment: hai toscho, I have installed your plugin and it sanitized the file name as you have mentioned. Now just a request from my side - can please sanitize the file name with only the combination of alpha-numeric (abc/123) and hyphen (-) only. Don't want any other symbol in between. e.g 'malic-html-00.jpg'. If you can just make it happen with your plugin then I'll be really grateful to you.

Comment: @wpCallCenter You need your own additional filter for that. I don’t think my plugin should this.